# Making a composite scrollable

Tags: swt, jface

I am very new to SWT and JFace. I have to fix a bug for which I am required to add a scroll bar to a composite. I tried changing it to Scrolled Composite and setting the attribute bits and then enabling vertical and horizontal expand but to no avail.

```java
FormToolkit tk = this.toolkit; 
Composite             consistencyCheckComposite;   
this.consistencyCheckComposite = tk.createComposite(this.consistencyCheckSection );
//this.consistencyCheckComposite = new ScrolledComposite( this.parentComposite, SWT.V_SCROLL | SWT.H_SCROLL );
gd = new GridData( SWT.FILL, SWT.BEGINNING, true, true );
this.consistencyCheckComposite.setLayoutData( gd );
this.consistencyCheckComposite.setBackground( this.parentComposite.getBackground() );
GridLayout consistencyCheckGridLayout = new GridLayout();
consistencyCheckGridLayout.numColumns = 4;
consistencyCheckGridLayout.horizontalSpacing = DEFAULT_SPACING * 3; // 15
this.consistencyCheckComposite.setLayout( consistencyCheckGridLayout );
this.consistencyCheckComposite = tk.createComposite( this.consistencyCheckSection );
//this.consistencyCheckComposite = new ScrolledComposite( this.parentComposite, SWT.V_SCROLL | SWT.H_SCROLL );
gd = new GridData( SWT.FILL, SWT.BEGINNING, true, true );
this.consistencyCheckComposite.setLayoutData( gd );
this.consistencyCheckComposite.setBackground( this.parentComposite.getBackground() );
GridLayout consistencyCheckGridLayout = new GridLayout();
consistencyCheckGridLayout.numColumns = 4;
consistencyCheckGridLayout.horizontalSpacing = DEFAULT_SPACING * 3; // 15
this.consistencyCheckComposite.setLayout( consistencyCheckGridLayout );
```

Comment: First of all, you need to tell the ScrolledComposite the content that should be scrolled with `sc.setContent()`

Comment: @RüdigerHerrmann : The content is being set somewhere. I  can see data properly with the above mentioned approach but when data exceeds the length of the composite then excess data becomes invisible for which i need a scrolled composite. Strangely when i changed the composite type to Scrolled Composite it threw an exception saying **LayoutComposite** (returned from **tk.createComposite()**) cannot be casted to **scrolledComposite**.

Comment: The code you posted doesn't tell much about your actual problem. A standalone, self-contained snippet would be good to reproduce your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Problem here may be with your gridData last two parameters which refers to grabExcessHorizontalSpace and grabExcessVerticalSpace. It may change the composit size according to the contents on composite. You should create a fix size composite.

Your code is not clear enough to tell the problem. Try to provide more detailed code.